# Java application slow because of heap

Tags: java, performance, jvm, tomcat6

We have serious application issue at peak time application get very very slow and when i check on AppDynamics matrix, my heap memory is full and GC kicked in every minute and that make it very very slow. here is the configuration of my java (tomcat)

```
OS version is Redhat 5 Linux

java version "1.6.0_05" 64Bit
```

Java options are `-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC`

Major GC collection time spend per min (ms)

[image]

CMS Old Gen usage in MB

[image]

Par Eden space in MB

[image]

Any suggestion why par eden space and old gen hitting hard line?

## **UPDATE**

Here is the last 12 Hour picture of Heap usage and Major GC collection (in Green dots), GC was very high between `3:00AM to 7:00AM` but when i restart application around `7:30AM` everything is good and application response time was very fast, why reboot fixed everything?

[image]

## **Hurray! 4GB Heap solved problem**

Major GC collection time spend per min (ms) after 4GB (Zero Major GC)

[image]

CMS Old Gen usage in MB after 4GB Heap

[image]

Par Eden space in MB after 4GB Heap

[image]

Comment: The problem is not about configuration, but about code optimization. Actually, this problem isn't a trivial one. You should read about it a little http://plumbr.eu/blog. They can assist you with memory leak localization.

Comment: what are those graphs from?

Comment: AppDynamics JVM monitor

Comment: So how did you solve the problem?

Comment: we increase heap memory to 4GB after running some test, It seem our application is quite hungry because we are running very log reports. I will post new graph with 4GB matrix tomorrow..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One major GC per minute doesn't at all seem troublesome. Usually it takes about half a second, so that's 1/120th of your overall CPU usage. It is also quite natural that heavy application load results in more memory allocation. Apparently you are allocating some objects that live on for a while (could be caching).

My conclusion: the demonstrated GC behavior is not a proof that there is something wrong with your application's memory allocation.

### UPDATE

I have looked more carefully at your diagrams (unfortunately they are quite difficult to read). You don't have one GC per min; you have 60 *seconds* of major GC per minute, which would mean it's happening all the time. That *does* look like major trouble; in fact in those conditions you usually get an OOME due to "GC time percentage threshold crossed". Note that the CMS collector which you are using is actually slower than the default one; its advantage is only that it doesn't "stop the world" as much. It may not be the best choice for you. But you do look to either have a memory leak, or a general issue in program design.

Comment: Do you think i need to increase memory? its `2GB` currently.

Comment: I have updated my answer. After carefully looking into your diagrams, they paint a quite different picture than what you state in the question text.

Comment: What is the quick work around? because looking into code and trying to fix thing will require more time.. if i can make it workable for few days that would be good too

Comment: But after restart tomcat my application is fine and very responsive, how that happened? check my updated question

Comment: It is quite likely that you have a memory leak of some kind. This behavior is typical of such a situation.

Answer (score 2):

When JVM reaches heap maximum size, GC is called more frequently to prevent OOM exception. Normal program execution should not happen at such circumstances. When a new object is allocated and JVM cant get enough of free space, GC is called. This might postpone object allocation process and thus slowdown overall performance. Garbage collection happens not concurrently in this case and you do not benefit from CMS collector. Try to play with `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction`, its default value is about 90%. Setting this parameter to lower values, will force garbage collection before application reaches heap maximum. Thus GC will work in parallel with application not clashing with it. Have a look at article [Starting a Concurrent Collection Cycle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#cms.starting_a_cycle).

Answer (score 1):

Are you always waiting for GC to take care of removing unused references? Is there some places in your application that you know a reference to a heavy weight object won't be used anymore from that point, but it is not manually nulled? Perhaps setting such heavy weight objects to null manually at the right places could prevent them growing till they hit the end of the heap....